# Recyclerview loses edge effect when placed inside NestedScrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to place a recyclerview inside a nested scroll view. Following is my layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nestedscrollview">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <fragment
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:name="com.example.nestedscrollviewexample.ItemFragment"
                android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
                android:id="@+id/itemfragment"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</FrameLayout>
```

The fragment contains a simple Recylerview.

What i notice is that if the recyclerview is outside the NestedScrollView then it retains it edge effects. However when i place the recycler view inside the nestedscrollview the edge effects are gone.

Instead, when i add the following line-

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false);
```

I notice that edge effects are visible but only for the edge of nested scrollview. How can i retain the edge effect for the recycler view as well?

For better clarity i am sharing 2 images -

1. First is Recyclerview edge effect before adding it to nested scroll view. 
   [[image: Recyclerview edge effect before adding it to nested scroll view]]
2. The one below is when we add recycler view to a nested scroll view-
   [image]

I would like to have the recyclerview inside the nested scrollview and also keep its edge effects. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not you remove this effect? Set `android:overScrollMode="never"` on RecyclerView.

Comment: I want to show this effect not remove it.

Comment: NestedScrollView is used to prevent scrolling issues while having multiple scrolling views. When you have wrap your RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView then RV scrolling behaviour is intercepted by NestedScrollView. So RV will not show this effect when it is wrapped in NestedSV.

Comment: Please, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Adding android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" to the RV fixed it for me.